# Como enviar una lista grande de objetos Json mediante una petición ajax con JQuery en .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Estoy enviando una lista grande de objectos, sin embargo al enviarlos por una petición ajax me sale el error: "Json demasiado grande":

```js
function savePermissions(pLstObjPermissions) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Security/SavePermission",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(pLstObjPermissions),
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.success) {
                        showAlert("Permisos web", "Has actualizado correctamente los permisos web.", "success");
                        resetForm();
                    }
                    else {
                        showMessage("Permisos web", response.message, "error");
                    };
                },
                error: function (request, status, exception) {
                    showMessage("Permisos web", exception, "error");
                }
            });
        };
```

Donde `pLstObjPermissions` es igual a:

```json
[{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":3,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":27,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":22,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":23,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":24,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":25,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":26,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":4,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":14,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":15,"AllowAccess":true},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":5,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":40,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":39,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":47,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":48,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":41,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":42,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":43,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":44,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":45,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":38,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":18,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":19,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":17,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":46,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":20,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":6,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":13,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":7,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":9,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":10,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":11,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":12,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":12,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":30,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":31,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":32,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":8,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":33,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":34,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":35,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":36,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":9,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":7,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":8,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":10,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":1,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":2,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":3,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":4,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":21,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":37,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":1,"AccessId":11,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":5,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":2,"AccessId":6,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":1,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":2,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":3,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":4,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":5,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":6,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":7,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":8,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":9,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":10,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":11,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":12,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":13,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":14,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":15,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":16,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":17,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":18,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":19,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":20,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":21,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":22,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":23,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":24,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":25,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":26,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":27,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":28,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":29,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":30,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":31,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":32,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":33,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":34,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":35,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":36,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":37,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":38,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":39,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":40,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":41,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":42,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":43,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":44,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":45,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":46,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":47,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":48,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":49,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":50,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":51,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":52,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":53,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":54,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":55,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":56,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":57,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":58,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":59,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":60,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":61,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":62,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":63,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":64,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":65,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":66,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":67,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":68,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":69,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":70,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":71,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":72,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":73,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":74,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":75,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":76,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":77,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":78,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":79,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":80,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":81,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":82,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":83,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":84,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":85,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":86,"AllowAccess":false},{"Id":0,"PermissionType":2,"PermissionId":0,"AccessType":5,"AccessId":87,"AllowAccess":false}]
```

Son como 256 objetos en la lista

Del lado del servidor el codigo es el siguiente:

```cs
public ActionResult SavePermission(IList<Permission> pLstObjPermissions)
        {
            var lLstObjResult = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            try
            {
                SecurityFactory.GetPermissionService().SaveOrUpdatePermissions(pLstObjPermissions);
                lLstObjResult.Add(MESSAGE, "Registro guardado exitosamente");
                lLstObjResult.Add(SUCCESS, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lLstObjResult.Add(MESSAGE, e.Message);
                lLstObjResult.Add(SUCCESS, false);
            }

            return Json(lLstObjResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Nota: en el web.config ya tengo especificado el tamaño de las peticiones.

```xml
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
    <!--<customErrors mode="On" >-->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" >
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="/Error/401" />
      <error statusCode="402" redirect="/Error/402" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error/403" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/404" />
      <error statusCode="405" redirect="/Error/405" />
      <error statusCode="406" redirect="/Error/406" />
      <error statusCode="407" redirect="/Error/407" />
      <error statusCode="408" redirect="/Error/408" />
      <error statusCode="409" redirect="/Error/409" />
      <error statusCode="410" redirect="/Error/410" />
      <error statusCode="411" redirect="/Error/411" />
    </customErrors>  
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="65536" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se debe agregar el elemento `aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` a la sección `<appSettings>` de tu archivo **web.config**, poniendo como valor **`2147483647`** que es el equivalente al valor máximo de un tipo de dato `Int32`.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

En está página de la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx), podrás encontrar toda la información acerca de los elementos así como su uso.

Nota: en la sección de la documentación oficial se recomienda no ajustar al valor máximo ya que representa un riesgo de seguridad. Lo ideal será que revises el número de elementos que deseas deserializar e intentar realizar un estimado tomando como referencia el tamaño máximo del json que estás usando.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente resolví este problema enviando la lista como un string y deserializandolo del lado del servidor, no creo que sea la mejor practica pero funciona de momento:

```js
function savePermissions(pLstObjPermissions) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Security/SavePermission",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({pStrPermissions: JSON.stringify(pLstObjPermissions)}),
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.success) {
                        showAlert("Permisos web", "Has actualizado correctamente los permisos web.", "success");
                        resetForm();
                    }
                    else {
                        showMessage("Permisos web", response.message, "error");
                    };
                },
                error: function (request, status, exception) {
                    showMessage("Permisos web", exception, "error");
                }
            });
        };
```

```cs
public ActionResult SavePermission(string pStrPermissions)
        {
            var lLstObjResult = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            try
            {
                SecurityFactory.GetPermissionService().SaveOrUpdatePermissions(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Pemission>>(pStrPermissions));
                lLstObjResult.Add(MESSAGE, "Registro guardado exitosamente");
                lLstObjResult.Add(SUCCESS, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lLstObjResult.Add(MESSAGE, e.Message);
                lLstObjResult.Add(SUCCESS, false);
            }

            return Json(lLstObjResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Si tienen una mejor manera, favor de compartirla.